# how to remove json object key and valyue in QT/c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a json file as shown below

```
{
    "TestId:1": {
        "FILE ID": "223",
        "CLASS": "rame",
        "PLATFORM": "test"
    },

    "TestId:2": {
        "FILE ID": "123",
        "CLASS": "raj",
        "PLATFORM": "test2"
    }
}
```

I want to remove the `"TestId:2"` key content.

I tried `delete obj["TestId:2"];` but that did not worked. It is deleting only the key `"TestId:2"`

I want to delete key **with** the value.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a QJsonObject to edit it.

First, read your file:

```
QFile file("myfile.json"); // to replace with you file name
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray data = file.readAll();
file.close();
```

Then, create the QJsonDocument with the data from the file:

```
QJsonParseError error;
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data, &error);
```

Then get the root object of the document:

```
QJsonObject root = doc.object();
```

Remove the element in the object, for exemple:

```
root.remove("TestId:2");
```

Then create a new document with the modified element:

```
doc = QJsonDocument(root);
```

And finally write the file again:

```
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
file.write(doc.toJson());
file.close();
```

And that should do the job.
As usual, there are many checks to add everywhere (file open, JSON parsing, etc).